# Proxy Setting in Teamcity

Tags: ssl-certificate, teamcity, jira

We have teamcity 10 running as a service behind a corporate network and we need to configure it to connect to a proxy so we can access an external issue tracker (Jira).

When we attempt a test connection we get

> Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am assuming that is because the proxy isn't setup properly? Other links seem to suggest its a certificate issue for Jira Cloud? Alternative theory based on this https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/JIRA and https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice suggest that xml-rpc is required for the integration however that is deprecated?

We have added

> TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS in environment settings with the following
>   -Dproxyset=true;-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx;-Dhttp.proxyPort=xxx

Is there anything else? Or a simpler way?

Thanks for reading

Comment: TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS should get space-delimited settiongs, not ";"-delimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the HTTPS certificate of your Jira is self-signed, so you will need to configure TeamCity server JVM by [adding](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server#UsingHTTPStoaccessTeamCityserver-JVMConfiguration) the root certificate of your organization into JVM keystore as trusted.